# Codeigniter Delete From Database Based on Class of HTML Element

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter. I generate a view that contains a table within a form with `<tr>`s like this:

```
    <tr>
      <td><input name="set[2][order]" value="3">
          <input type="hidden" name="set[2][ex_id]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input name="set[2][weight]" value="60.00"></td>
      <td><input name="set[2][reps]" value="5"></td>
      <td><img class="deleteRowButton" src="/assets/images/icons/png/delete-3x.png" border="0" alt="Delete Set" title="Toggle Delete Set"/></td>
    </tr>
```

I have a little jQuery script that toggles the class of the `<tr>` when the img 'delete-3x.png' is clicked:

```
<script>
$('.deleteRowButton').click (function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass( "deleteSet" );
});
</script>
```

so it looks like this:

```
<tr class="deleteSet">
```

All this does so far is change the opacity of the `<tr>` so I make it looks greyed out, just to signify that it has been selected for deleting.

What i want to achieve when the user submits the form and am not sure how to handle in CI, is somewhere along the line, in plain English code, saying:

```
if tr class = "deleteSet", then delete from db
```

At the moment all inputs are just written to database. so I need a way of recognising that the user want to remove an entry.

Comment: can't you send ajax request when user clicks on `delete` and send the id for that row , then remove row in ajax sucess handler?

Answer (score 0):

You need different logic, your backend will never know HTML class. It can only know POST/GET params.

What I recommend is:

1. User clicks on DeleteSet button on current line item.
2. Javascript adds that line item ID to somewhere (in memory or as HTML hidden property)
3. When you press "save" button it will send list of ID's that you want to delete.

#### Psudo Example

HTML

```
<tr>
      <td><input name="set[2][order]" value="3"> <input class="set-id" type="hidden" name="set[2][ex_id]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input name="set[2][weight]" value="60.00"></td>
      <td><input name="set[2][reps]" value="5"></td>
      <td><img class="deleteRowButton" src="/assets/images/icons/png/delete-3x.png" border="0" alt="Delete Set" title="Toggle Delete Set"/></td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$('.deleteRowButton').click (function() {
    $(this).disable(); // Don't want to duplicate ids
    var id = $('.set-id', $(this).closest('tr')).val();

    $('.submit-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="delete[]" value="' + id + '" />');
    // Now when form will be submitted it will be populated with item ids you want to delete
});
```

Comment: Hi @Steve thanks for the answers, sound most like what I want to do. So is `.submit-form` just a reference to whatever my form is called? So I can add stuff to the bottom of it? How does `var id = $('.set-id', $(this).closest('tr')).val();` work? How does it get the value of `2` in this case? Will try and implement this thanks.

Comment: also I think this: `$('.submit-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="delete[]" value="' + id + "' />);` should be this: `$('.submit-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="delete[]" value="' + id + '" />');`

Comment: @j0nr Yes and Yes. :)

Answer (score 0):

- write one function in controller which delete item by id

Html :

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="set[2][order]" value="3">
          <input type="hidden" name="set[2][ex_id]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input name="set[2][weight]" value="60.00"></td>
      <td><input name="set[2][reps]" value="5"></td>
      <td><img  class="deleteRowButton" url="/your-controller-name/method-name/item-id" src="/assets/images/icons/png/delete-3x.png" border="0" alt="Delete Set" title="Toggle Delete Set"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Js:

```
$('.deleteRowButton').off('click').on('click',function(){
                                var _this = $(this);
                                var url = $(_this).attr('url');
                                $.post(url,function(data){
                                    $(_this).parents('tr').remove();
                            });
                        });
```